# Physics simulator in water python

Tags: python, pygame, physics, simulator

I'm having issues understanding how to simulate a situation like this: http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/density-and-buoyancy/buoyancy_en.html

The point of the program is to make a simulator - like the one in the link. I want to keep it realistic and use Python. I want to draw the simulation in [Pygame](http://pygame.org).

In my program I ask for a couple of variables; the mass and the radius. The radius will be used to calculate the volume of a sphere and the mass will be used to calculate the buoyancy, gravity force and acceleration.

But the thing is, to keep everything in SI-units I ask for the radius in metre. Doing this while keeping my radius under 10cm, makes for a really small number. And when I use the Pygame module to draw a sphere at the size of 0.1m, it fails. So instead of doing that, I needed to use a bigger scale.

So here comes my main problem. How exacly should I scale the sphere? Say I wanted to define 100 pixels to be 1 metre. I would then have to multiply my radius by 100, since that would be the scale, but now that the sphere is bigger should the velocity also be multiplied by 100?

I've gotten really confused over this! Thanks for your time.

Don't know if you need to see this, anyhow.
Calculations.py

```
import math

class Formulas():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pi = 3.1415926535
        self.gravity = 9.82 #m/s^2
        self.density_water = 1000.0 #kg/m^3
        self.density_air   = 1.29 #kg/m^3
        self.drag_sphere   = 0.47

    def object_buoyancy(self, volume, medium_density):
        buoyancy = volume * medium_density * self.gravity #N
        return buoyancy

    def object_gravity(self, mass):
        gravity_force = mass * self.gravity #N
        return gravity_force

    def object_volume_sphere(self, radius):
        volume  = 1.3333333 * self.pi * math.pow(radius, 3) #m^3
        return volume

    def object_mass(self, density, volume):
        mass = volume * density #kg
        return mass

    def object_acceleration(self, gravity_force, buoyancy, mass):
        total_force = gravity_force - buoyancy #N
        acceleration = total_force / mass #m/s^2
        return acceleration

    def object_speed(self, acceleration, time, scale):
        speed  = acceleration * (float(time)/1000.0) #m/s
        return speed

    def surface_area(self, radius):
        area = 4 * self.pi * math.pow(radius, 2)
        return area
```

Comment: You should be able to define everything in "display units" by replacing 1 m = 100px everywhere you need to display something. You already keep track of units of everything, so it shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: Okay, so when I diplay my sphere, all I need to do is make it 100 times bigger? I don't need to increase the speed accordingly?

Comment: @SimonBob You will need to scale *everything* by the scale-factor.

Comment: @hayden So it's as simple as multiplying by the scale factor in every return statement?

Comment: @SimonBob everything which you are displaying... That is, if you were going to display an object as 100px by 100px, you scale it to 200px by 200px etc, and it's location is also scaled... (you don't change the maths above just how it's displayed)

Comment: @hayden I'm only displaying the sphere and a blue background. But what troubles me is; when I use my formula for speed, I get my results in [m/s], but I made a scale factor of 100:1. Shouldn't the speed be multiplied by the scale factor aswell then?

Comment: @SimonBob in *some* sense, if it were travelling at 1px/s it will now be at 2px/s. But this is in the *display* part... Do it all the maths in `m` then convert `m` to px when drawing stuff.

Comment: @SimonBob, hayden is exactly right, just change things for the display part, keep your calculations in physical units. Then when you display convert meters into pixels with some factor you picked. You probably don't even need to convert speeds (since you might only deal with coordinates), but 1 m/s would become 100 px/s by the same unit conversion.

Comment: It may help to think of it as converting world to screen coordinates/scaling. Your object might be at (200,100) world, but it could render to (0,0) on screen. Similar to how scrolling tilemaps convert coordinates on display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so many problems in physics, this one can be solved using [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Let us take a look at those constants you defined:

```
self.pi = 3.1415926535
self.gravity = 9.82 #m/s^2
self.density_water = 1000.0 #kg/m^3
self.density_air   = 1.29 #kg/m^3
self.drag_sphere   = 0.47
```

In order to be consistent and scale all of your distances so that `1 m = 100 px`, we need to scale your constants:

```
self.pi = 3.1415926535
self.gravity = 982.0 #px/s^2
self.density_water = 0.001 #kg/px^3
self.density_air   = 0.00000129 #kg/px^3
self.drag_sphere   = 0.47
```

The only other thing you have to do is increase your `radius` variable by a factor of 100.  After that, the rest of your calculations will fall in line:

1. Your volume calculation will be correct, so
2. Your mass and surface area calculations will change, so
3. Your gravity and bouyancy will change, so
4. Your acceleration will change, so
5. Finally, your velocity will be correct.

In your equations/methods, I do not see where your `medium_density` is set, so that my have to change as well. But, in the end, all you have to do is scale all of your inputs that have a unit of "distance" and your output variable will be scaled correctly.